# producer consumer with semaphores giving segmanetation fault

Tags: c

so im trying to get this program with semaphores to work.
finally got rid of all of the errors, and now its giving me a core dump issue?
trying to figure out what im doing wrong, been working this all morning and cant seem to find the issue.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 20

 char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
 int nextIn = 0;
 int nextOut = 0;


  //char sem_name1[] = "mutex";
  //char sem_name2[] = "empty_slots";
  //char sem_name3[] = "full_slots";
 sem_t *empty_slots;
 sem_t *full_slots;
 sem_t *mutex;

typedef struct {
 char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
 int nextIn;
 int nextOut;
} shared_data;




void Put(char item){
 sem_wait(empty_slots);
 sem_wait(mutex);
 buffer[nextIn] = item;
 nextIn = (nextIn + 1) % BUFF_SIZE;
 sem_post(mutex);
 printf("Producing %c ...\n", item);
 sem_post(full_slots);
}
void * Producer(){
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  sleep(rand()%6);
  Put((char)('A'+ i % 26));
 }
}
void Get(char item){
 sem_wait(full_slots);
 sem_wait(mutex);
 item= buffer[nextOut]; 
 nextOut = (nextOut + 1) % BUFF_SIZE;
 sem_post(mutex);
 printf("Consuming %c ...\n", item);
 sem_post(empty_slots);
}
void * Consumer(){
 int i;
 char  item;
 for(i = 0; i < 15; i++){
 sleep(rand()%6);
 Get(item);
 }
}
void main(){
 sem_init(empty_slots, 0, 1);
 sem_init(full_slots, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
 sem_init(mutex, 0, 1);
/* Initialize semaphores */
pthread_t pid, cid;
pthread_create(&pid, NULL, Producer, NULL);
pthread_create(&cid, NULL, Consumer, NULL);
// create  more consumer & producer threads.  
pthread_join(pid, NULL);
pthread_join(cid, NULL);
}
```

when i use gdb i get the error

```
(gdb) 
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
* 1    Thread 0xb7de8700 (LWP 3567) "labp2" __new_sem_init (sem=0x0, pshared=0, value=1)
    at sem_init.c:60
(gdb)
```

Comment: Your semaphores are not allocated.

Comment: I don't understand how this compiles with no warnings/errors.......

Comment: @MartinJames, easy. `-fpermissive` will compile almost anything :) And who even looks at warning as long as an executable is produced?

Comment: Note that @EugeneSh.is hinting that 'sem_init(empty_slots, 0, 1);' cannot possibly modify 'empty_slots' since it's passed by value.

Comment: im not sure where to go with that hint. i literally have never even taken c. my buddy just asked me to look at it for him, i googled and fixed until there were no errors. now im really stuck.